# How to do x2go Remote Login for Machine Initialization?

Tags: vnc, remote-desktop, remote-management

I am a cloud computer user.
In order to create a new virtual machine in the cloud, usually I have to initialize it using `vnc viewer` in the cloud control panel before I can access it with `x2go client`.
What I mean by machine initialization is setting username and password in that new machine.

In some occasion, the control panel vnc viewer can't be accessed. Is there any possibilities to access it by `x2go client` directly?

My computer have an internal and external IP address.
Thanks for any possible suggestions.